# How to calculate the percentage of each element in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have this list with 5 sequence of numbers:

```
['123', '134', '234', '214', '223']
```

and I want to obtain the percentage of each number `1, 2, 3, 4` in the `ith` position of each sequence of numbers. For example, the numbers at `0th` position of this `5` sequences of numbers are `1 1 2 2 2`, then I need to calculate the percentage of 
`1, 2, 3, 4` in this sequence of numbers and return the percentage as `0th` element of a new list.

```
['123', '134', '234', '214', '223']

0th position: 1 1 2 2 2   the percentage of 1,2,3,4 are respectively: [0.4, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0]

1th position: 2 3 3 1 2   the percentage of 1,2,3,4 are respectively: [0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.0]

2th position: 3 4 4 4 3   the percentage of 1,2,3,4 are respectively: [0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.6]]
```

Then desired result is to return:

```
[[0.4, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0], [0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.6]]
```

My attempt so far:

```
list(zip(*['123', '134', '234', '214', '223']))
```

Result:

```
 [('1', '1', '2', '2', '2'), ('2', '3', '3', '1', '2'), ('3', '4', '4', '4', '3')]
```

But I got stuck here, then I don't know how to calculate the percentage of the element of each numbers of `1, 2, 3, 4`, then obtain the desired result. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `count(i)` to determine to number of occurrences of the numbers 1-4 and divide it by 5 to obtain the percentage:

```
sequence=list(zip(*['123', '134', '234', '214', '223']))
percentages=[]
for x in sequence:
    t=list(x)
    temp=[t.count(str(i))/len(x) for i in range(1,5)]  #work out the percentage of each number
    percentages.append(temp) #add percentages to list
```

Or, as one list comprehension:

```
percentages=[[list(x).count(str(i))/len(x) for i in range(1,5)]for x in sequence]
```

Output:

```
[[0.4, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0], [0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.6]]
```

Comment: Too much hard-coding. `/5` should be replaced by `/len(x)`, and `range(1,5)` should be replaced by `set(''.join(l))` (and you can then replace `str(i)` with just `i`).

Answer (score 4):

starting from your approach, you could do the rest with a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

for item in zip(*['123', '134', '234', '214', '223']):
    c = Counter(item)
    total = sum(c.values())
    percent = {key: value/total for key, value in c.items()}
    print(percent)

    # convert to list
    percent_list = [percent.get(str(i), 0.0) for i in range(5)]
    print(percent_list)
```

which prints

```
{'2': 0.6, '1': 0.4}
[0.0, 0.4, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0]
{'2': 0.4, '3': 0.4, '1': 0.2}
[0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.0]
{'4': 0.6, '3': 0.4}
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.6]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could start by creating the zipped list as you did:

```
zipped = zip(*l)
```

then map an `itertools.Counter` to it as to get the counts of each item in the results from `zip`:

```
counts = map(Counter, zipped)
```

and then go through it, creating a list out of their counts divided by their sizes:

```
res = [[c[i]/sum(c.values()) for i in '1234'] for c in counts]
print(res) 
[[0.4, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0], [0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.6]]
```

If you are a one-liner kind of person, mush the first two in the comprehension to get this in one line:

```
res = [[c[i]/sum(c.values()) for i in '1234'] for c in map(Counter, zip(*l))]
```

additionally, as noted in a comment, if you don't know the elements ahead of time, `sorted(set(''.join(l)))` could replace `'1234'`.

Comment: If you don't know the elements ahead of time, `set(''.join(l))` should replace `'1234'`.

Comment: @Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard  Thanks for your solution, but I don't very understand this syntax `[[c[i]/sum(c.values()) for i in '1234'] for c in map(Counter, zip(*l))]` because I am not very familiar with `map`  function. I checked and got to know that it may mean to apply the function `Counter` on  `zip(*l))` , then I thought why not directly use `Counter(zip(*l))` , but i found `Counter(zip(*l))` do not work. Then I checked and found `map(Counter, zip(*l))` returns  `<map object at 0x033C1930>` . I don't know what it means. Could you explain for me why `map(Counter, zip(*l))`  works?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just extending @hiro protagonist.
Changes marked as coments

```
from collections import Counter

lis = ['123', '134', '234', '214', '223'] 

symbols = {c for s in lis for c in s} # in case you take lis as input from user

percent_list = []

for item in zip(*lis):
    c = Counter(item)
    total = sum(c.values())
    percent = {key: value/total for key, value in c.items()}

    # convert to list, 0.0 is default value
    
    percent_list.append([percent.get(i, 0.0) for i in sorted(symbols)]) # Your comment even says. But then you don't make a list you create a generator.
    
    
sequence = list(zip(*lis))
sorted_s = list(sorted(symbols))


for index, item in enumerate(zip(*lis)):
    str_s_s = ','.join(sorted_s) # as pointed by @BallpointBen
    str_seque =  ' '.join(sequence[index])
    print(f"{index}th position: {str_seque} the percentage of {str_s_s} are respectively: {percent_list[index]}")
```

Gives desired output

```
0th position: 1 1 2 2 2 the percentage of 1,2,3,4 are respectively: [0.4, 0.6, 0.0, 0.0]
1th position: 2 3 3 1 2 the percentage of 1,2,3,4 are respectively: [0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.0]
2th position: 3 4 4 4 3 the percentage of 1,2,3,4 are respectively: [0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.6]

[Program finished]
```